# Wait for Android app to display a React Native button and then touch it

Tags: appium, react-native

I'm developing a React Native app for Android and I've been learning and trying to do my first test in Ruby. Right now I would like my test to wait for the app's main screen to load and then touch a React 'TouchableOpacity' button.
The React Native code is the following:

```
<View style={styles.row}>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonIcon} onPress={this.goToFaqsList.bind(this)} accessible={true} accessibility_id={'FAQs'}>
        <Icon style={styles.icon} size={32} name="help" color="white"> </Icon>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>FAQ's</Text>
    </View>
<View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
```

The test:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'

capabilities = {
  platformName:  'Android',
  deviceName:    'Android',
  app:           '~/workspace/maps2/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk',
}

server_url = "http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"

# Start the driver
Appium::Driver.new(caps: capabilities).start_driver

Appium.promote_appium_methods Object

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new :timeout => 10
wait.until { elementByAccessibilityId("FAQs").displayed? }

source
mobileElement = elementByAccessibilityId("FAQs")
puts(mobileElement)

driver_quit
```

The " elementByAccessibilityId " was an approach I saw in another topic but I'm getting an error:

```
Failure/Error: wait.until { elementByAccessibilityId("FAQs").displayed? }

NoMethodError:
undefined method `elementByAccessibilityId' for main:Object
```

Can someone tell my mistake and point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: did you try it running in release mode?

Comment: I wasn't running the app in release, but now I'm doing it. It does makes sense to run it as release if we're doing this kind of tests, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working: in the React Native code I changed the attribute accessibility_id={'FAQs'} to accessibilityLabel={'FAQ'}, and in the ruby test file the correct method is find_element(:accessibility_id, 'FAQs'). And it's working! Now I can .click() the button and continue testing.

https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/blob/master/docs/android_docs.md to see what other functions we have available to use.